# Programaticly add multiple labels to WPF grid

Tags: c#, wpf

my old winform example:

[image]

I have a blank grid that I need to add some dynamic generated labels to in a foreach

I am using this to create the label and set the Name to a id i need to use later on.

```
this.LayoutRoot.Children.Add(new Label { Foreground = Brushes.White, HorizontalContentAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center, Background = Brushes.LightBlue, Content = Node.name, Height = 20, Width = 320, Name = "_" + Node.id});
```

i have tried

```
Grid.SetRow
```

with then new Label but it needs a UI Element passed to it, and as the label has not been created yet...

so currently the code just layers all the labels on top of each other in the center of the grid.

also tried

```
Grid.SetRow("_" + Node.id, i);
```

but name string format not supported, maybe there is another way to create and position the label

Thanks

Comment: You did not provided the scope of your implementation, so this is just a guess: maybe the `MVVM` pattern would be the perfect solution for your requirements. You may either learn the principle of the pattern first, or you may have a look at practical examples, starting from e. g. here: https://wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/itemscontrol/ to find out if this solution fits your needs.

Comment: Dont use a grid then! Use a StackPanel!

Comment: You're going the wrong way. WPF is not intended to be used like that. WPF is not WinForms. Do not construct your UI in code. Instead, use the powerful styling and templating mechanisms, together with data binding.

Comment: @dymanoid can you remove / add controls on a timer (30s) with data returned from an api call not via code? Thanks

Comment: @DwayneDibbley, yes, you can. See MVVM for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick for you!
 You can use the `.SetValue()` method.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Label lbl = new Label { Foreground = Brushes.White, HorizontalContentAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center, Background = Brushes.LightBlue, Content = "name" + i, Height = 20, Width = 320, Name = "_" + i };
            lbl.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, i);
            this.LayoutRoot.Children.Add(lbl);

        }
```

this assumes your grid looks something like this:

```
<Grid Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

But if all you want to do is stack Labels next to each other you should use a StackPanel instead of a grid!

Edit:
You updated your question all you have to do to achive that is changing the grid to a stackpanel then they will stac automatically. Btw you are basically building a ListBox here...why not use a ListBox in first place?

Comment: Thanks, StackPanel was the pointer i needed for this simple app, and i will look ate MVVM options for the future